# Calling a jsp method from anathor jsp page

Tags: jsp

I have a method in a JSP page and I want to call that method from another JSP page. Both the JSP pages are in the same package. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

Unless a JSP includes another JSP, I do not believe this is possible.  Part of what allows a JSP to be recompiled and take effect immediately is that each JSP servlet class gets its own class loader, so that the class loader can be discarded and replaced when a JSP changes.

The decision to use a separate class loader for each page only works because of the assumption that JSP's don't reference each other.  Each JSP can only see down the class loader hierarchy, so they can access the classes under WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib, but they cannot see up or sideways in the hierarchy.

In other words, JSP's are the entry-points.  They are the roots of the dependency graph.  Anything common between them needs to either be an include file or moved into a dedicated Java class.

Comment: you mean to say that firstly i need to include the jsp page(say example.jsp) having a method(say mymethod()) and then call the method as mymethod()..is it?

Comment: If you want to keep the shared code in a JSP, then you need to move the function into a dedicated JSP include file and include the function in both pages.  Having one page include an entire other page is probably not a good way to go.